# How can I install Python3.6 in windows sandbox?

Tags: python-3.6, windows-sandbox

I want to use Python3.6 in windows sandbox, I installed the same in my windows host machine at
`C:\Users\Local_Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\`

I tried passing python to sandbox through configuration file as mapped folder but no luck.

```
<HostFolder>C:\Users\Local_Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\</HostFolder>
<SandboxFolder>C:\Users\Local_Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\</SandboxFolder>
```

I can use python36 in host machine as I set environment variable but not in sandbox, can anyone suggest why else need to be done?

Answer (score 0):

To make things easier on you, I would suggest you try using [Virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). It allows you to create a Sandbox environment so you can run python code without breaking anything. It has documentation and is easy to setup. I have used it in the past for windows.